# MongoDB LINQ query - Update records amended for User object - immutable _id error

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I'm trying to use MongoDB LINQ to update my user object's records that are updated, but I'm receiving the error:

"A Performing an update would modify the immutable field '_id'."

I create a user object as follows:

```
                var updateUser = new User
                {
                                 
                    firstname = userProfileFirstname,
                    surname = userProfileSurname,
                    dob = dateOfBirth,
                    userGender = userGender.ToString(),
                    userCountry = userCountry.ToString(),
                    
                };
                await MongoService.UpdateUser(updateUser, userId); //this is my own unique foreign Id - not an object ID
```

Then in my Mongo Services, I have the following Replace One Async query:

```
 public async static Task UpdateUser(User item, String fUserID)
        {
            var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("foreignId", fUserID);
            await UsersCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, item, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
}
```

Please could help with how I can fix this?

Comment: Somehow it looks like you are replacing _id, which is immutable; meaning, it can not be replaced.

Comment: Hi Yahya, I found this to be the reason for this error, however the problem is that I am not updating the bson document ID... it is defined in the model in order to save in another function which is why the Id element is null in my user object. I think this may be the problem? How can i get the update to ignore all of the null elements to avoid this error?

Comment: Your code isn't showing much of the update logic. So it is hard to say what's exactly going on.

Comment: if you're using `ReplaceOne`, you must first retrieve the `_id` from the db and set it on your `User` instance. other option is to use `UpdateOne` instead. or use something like [this](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/Entities-Save.html#partial-save-with-new-expression).

Comment: I tried ReplaceOne, and the error was that it doesn't contain an awaiter, so I removed async and await, which then returned the error, 'not all code paths return a value'. I don't need to add a return, I did try anyway but this didnt work either. I then tried UpdateOne and received the error, cannot convert from myproject.Models.User to Mongodb.Driver.UpdateDefinition<myProject.Models.User>. SavePreservingAsync isn't available for Mongodb. In the mean time, I have reverted to updating in code behind using c#, but it would be great to know what the working MongDB LINQ method was.